# Charge: send metadata to Stripe on same template as where it's collected

Tags: plugin-charge

I'm recording some custom data in Charge, but my client wants to see it within Stripe's control panel. I see you can set a `meta` array in `craft.charge.setPaymentOptions()` which should do the trick. But I'm collecting the custom data on the same page where I'm setting the payment options.

So for example, I've got a custom field called `giftAid`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fields[giftAid]" value="1"{{ charge is defined and charge.giftAid ? ' checked="checked"' }}>
```

On the same template I tried adding this to my payment options:

```
{% set options = {
    ... other options ...
    meta: {
        'giftAid': charge.giftAid
    }
} %}
{{ craft.charge.setPaymentOptions(options) }}
```

... but then I get the error `Variable "charge" does not exist.`

How can I pass this data to Stripe if it's only set when this form is submitted?